# Creating a for loop for all regular files and another loop to find # of lines, words, and characters

Tags: shell, loops, unix

```sh
#!/bin/bash

key="$1"

if [[ $# > 1 ]]; then
    echo "true"
    if [[ -d $key ]]; then
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false" >&2
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "false" >&2
    exit
fi

loop( for i in \`find . -name "*$1" -print\`)
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `find -type f | xargs wc` ?

Comment: It looks like you want check for the parameter `$1` being a directory and look for files with a name ending with `$1`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should start your script with `set -x` to better understand what's happening.

```
set -x
#!/bin/bash

key="$1"
if [[ $# > 1 ]]; then
    echo "true"
    if [[ -d $key ]]; then
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false" >&2
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "false" >&2
    exit
fi

for i in `find . -name "*$1" -print`
do
   wc $i
done
```

Hope this help, even though your goals remain unclear.